# Send a link to Daily Motion video to autoplay in HD mode

Tags: video, links, dailymotion

How can I provide a link to a Daily Motion video which starts automatically in HD?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if the video uploaded has a HD version to view.

If it does, follow these steps to send out a link that will autoplay in the highest resolution possible per video.

1. Click on your video to bring up its own page
2. Click on the <kbd>< ></kbd> toolbar button (bottom right of the video player)
3. Click "Other options" to open (on the right side under Settings)
4. From the **Default quality** drop down select box, select the highest one available.
   In our example it will be **HD720 (best quality)**
5. Click on another part of the pop up window, giving the dialog time to update the embed link it will generate.

   The embed code may look like this:

   ```
   <iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="323" 
   src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xu7heg?forcedQuality=hd720">
   </iframe><br />
   <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xu7heg_waiting-for-the-bus_fun" 
   target="_blank">Cyanide &amp; Happiness - Waiting for the Bus</a> <i>by 
   <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/Explosm" target="_blank">Explosm</a>
   </i>
   ```
6. Grab the first link and that will be your embed link preset to play with the highest quality the video is available in. This will load up in the entire browser window. If you want to show the whole page with the rest of the Daily Motion elements, remove the `embed/` part of the link for something like this:

   ```
   http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xu7heg?forcedQuality=hd720
   ```

Or you can just add this to the end of the URL:

```
?forcedQuality=hq
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do it, Dailymotion does not provides any support for custom URLs for its video, with pre-set settings.